# R - Assign same ID to polygons with same coordinates

Tags: grid, coordinates, polygon

I was given spatial data that is comprised in a grid but they didn't give me the grid per se (with each grid cell being a polygon), only the coordinates of the bottom left corner of the grid cell associated with the observation. They also told me that the size of each grid cell is 0.1 degrees.

From there i was able to recalculate for every row of my data frame the coordinates of the grid cell, like this :

```
latitude_left_corner longitude_left_corner latitude_right_corner longitude_right_corner
  -7.5                     43.8                         -7.6                      43.9                     
     
  -8.3                     43.7                         -8.4                      43.8                       
     
  -6.8                     43.7                         -6.9                      43.8                       
     
  -3.0                     43.4                         -3.1                      43.5                       
     
  -9.3                     43.7                         -9.4                      43.8                       
     
  -2.7                     43.5                         -2.8                      43.6
```

Then I was able to create the polygons associated with this command :

```
lst <- lapply(1:nrow(Coordinates), function(x){
  res <- matrix(c(Coordinates[x, 'longitude_left_corner'], Coordinates[x, 'latitude_left_corner'],
                  Coordinates[x, 'longitude_right_corner'], Coordinates[x, 'latitude_left_corner'],
                  Coordinates[x, 'longitude_right_corner'], Coordinates[x, 'latitude_right_corner'],
                  Coordinates[x, 'longitude_left_corner'], Coordinates[x, 'latitude_right_corner'],
                  Coordinates[x, 'longitude_left_corner'], Coordinates[x, 'latitude_left_corner'])  
                , ncol =2, byrow = T
  )
  st_polygon(list(res))
  
})
```

The problem I have is that I have to make understand to R that this is a grid and the polygons with the same coordinates are the same grid cell, I was thinking of giving them an ID so that I don't loose data in the process.

I have no idea how to do that, so if someone has an idea, thanks in advance!